# Update ListView content via JSON response without the use of service

Tags: android, ajax, json, algorithm, design-patterns

I'm thinking about this for a while now. Well I have some ideas about this but I know it won't work. Now what I wanted to achieve is for the adapter for listView to be updated automatically while the webservice that gives a response in JSON format works on the background.

Okay to give more idea I just wonder how does the facebook app pulls the updates without using the pull to refresh? I'm thinking of 1 way: they use service which runs let's say every 15 seconds and get's the updates. But can this be done on a more real time way just like on how an AJAX works?

Hope someone can give an ideas on this cause I really wanted to create an app which runs on a realtime updates but doesn't require that much of a memory on the device end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Google Cloud Messaging.

[image]

> Google Cloud Messaging for Android (GCM) is a free service that helps
>   developers send data from servers to their Android applications on
>   Android devices, and upstream messages from the user's device back to
>   the cloud. This could be a lightweight message telling the Android
>   application that there is new data to be fetched from the server (for
>   instance, a "new email" notification informing the application that it
>   is out of sync with the back end), or it could be a message containing
>   up to 4kb of payload data (so apps like instant messaging can consume
>   the message directly). The GCM service handles all aspects of queueing
>   of messages and delivery to the target Android application running on
>   the target device.

Here are the primary characteristics of Google Cloud Messaging (GCM):

1. It allows 3rd-party application servers to send messages to their
   Android applications.
2. Using the GCM Cloud Connection Server, you can receive upstream
   messages from the user's device.
3. An Android application on an Android device doesn't need to be
   running to receive messages. The system will wake up the Android
   application via Intent broadcast when the message arrives, as long
   as the application is set up with the proper broadcast receiver and
   permissions.
4. It does not provide any built-in user interface or other handling
   for message data. GCM simply passes raw message data received
   straight to the Android application, which has full control of how
   to handle it. For example, the application might post a
   notification, display a custom user interface, or silently sync
   data.
5. It requires devices running Android 2.2 or higher that also have the
   Google Play Store application installed, or or an emulator running
   Android 2.2 with Google APIs. However, you are not limited to
   deploying your Android applications through Google Play Store.
6. It uses an existing connection for Google services. For pre-3.0
   devices, this requires users to set up their Google account on their
   mobile devices. A Google account is not a requirement on devices
   running Android 4.0.4 or higher.

   See this [webpage](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html) for more details

Comment: Thanks! I will surely check this out.